# Tables not joinging properly [Error 10004]

Tags: sql, hive

```
Select count(*) cnt
from fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdhdr cdhdr
  Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos cdpos on (cdhdr.changenr = cdpos.changenr)
  Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekko  ekko on (ekko.lifnr = cdpos.objectid)
  Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekpo  ekpo on (ekpo.ebeln = ekko.ebeln)
where cdhdr.objectclas = 'KRED'
  and cdhdr.objectid = 'vendornumber'
  and cdpos.fname = 'ZTERM'
  and ekpo.elikz != 'X';


Select count(*) cnt
from fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdhdr xcdhdr
  Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos xcdpos on (xcdhdr.changenr = xcdpos.changenr)
 /* Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekko  xekko on (xekko.lifnr = xcdpos.objectid)*/
 /* Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekpo  xekpo on (xekpo.ebeln = xekko.ebeln)*/
  where xcdhdr.objectclas = 'KRED'
  and xcdhdr.objectid = 'vendornumber'
  and xcdpos.fname = 'ZTERM'
  /*and xekpo.elikz != 'X';*/

Select count(*) cnt
from /*fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdhdr xcdhdr
  Join*/ fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos xcdpos /*on (xcdhdr.changenr = xcdpos.changenr)*/
  Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekko  xekko on (xekko.lifnr = xcdpos.objectid)
 /* Join fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekpo  xekpo on (xekpo.ebeln = xekko.ebeln)*/
  where xcdhdr.objectclas = 'KRED'
  and xcdhdr.objectid = 'vendornumber'
  and xcdpos.fname = 'ZTERM'
  /*and xekpo.elikz != 'X';*/
```

The data base I am using is Hive, and I get the below error when I run this code. When I run all my joins separately everything works fine and data is returned.

As a side question I also would like the 'hdr' table there can be multiple results I would like it to produce the most recent change. I have tried the Max() but it errors out as well.

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:10155 Invalid table alias or column reference 'cdpos'

Comment: Why do you need the aliases at all the table names match your alias.

Comment: Because I do not want to write out the whole location every time. I have multiple choices for 'fin_sap_prd_tbls.' and I have to qualify it.

Comment: The exact code, I copied and pasted it. only change I made was I removed the true vendor number and replaced it with "vendor number"

Comment: @bkirby - Which version of hive are you using?

Comment: 2.3.4.7 is what I was told yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the alias names as the table names already match the alias.  The engine might be confused by having objects with the same name.

```
SELECT count(*) cnt
FROM fin_vsap_prd_tbls.cdhdr 
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos on (cdhdr.changenr = cdpos.changenr)
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekko  on (ekko.lifnr = cdpos.objectid)
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekpo  on (ekpo.ebeln = ekko.ebeln)
WHERE cdhdr.objectclas = 'KRED'
  and cdhdr.objectid = 'vendornumber'
  and cdpos.fname = 'ZTERM'
  and ekpo.elikz != 'X';
```

or name them differently...

```
SELECT count(*) cnt
FROM fin_vsap_prd_tbls.cdhdr  xcdhdr
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos xcdpos on (xcdhdr.changenr = xcdpos.changenr)
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekko  xekko on (xekko.lifnr = xcdpos.objectid)
  JOIN fin_sap_prd_tbls.ekpo  xekpo on (xekpo.ebeln = xekko.ebeln)
WHERE xcdhdr.objectclas = 'KRED'
  and xcdhdr.objectid = 'vendornumber'
  and xcdpos.fname = 'ZTERM'
  and xekpo.elikz != 'X';
```

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'and' 'cdhdr' '.':28:27,

The table is not qualified.

Comment: try alias with names not used (i just prefixed with x).  If we still have problems then I'd want confirmation that `objectclas` and `objectid` are valid fields in `fin_vsap_prd_tbls.cdhdr`

Comment: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:10590 Invalid table alias or column reference 'xcdpos':

same error as before.

Comment: are `fname`, `objectID`, and `changenr` in `fin_sap_prd_tbls.cdpos`?

Comment: yes, like I said before all the joins work separately and produce results. cdhdr>cdpos, cdpos>ekko, ekko>ekpo. when i put them together is where it fails.

Comment: Does it work (run w/o compile error [I know results would be wrong]) without the where clause? or just the 1st 2 criteria?  (I'm in a debugging mode now which means start taking things away until it works then figure out why adding back the 1 thing breaks it.)

Comment: No it does not work without a where clause. Runtime Exception

Comment: I have added in the original post some of my code with comment so you can see it. I believe the error is between lines 2 and 4 i get the same error with or without the ekpo table.